# Why does mvn command take forever?

Tags: maven

```
$ mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes=com.fasterxml.jackson.core
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/jooq/jooq-codegen-maven/3.9.1/jooq-codegen-maven-3.9.1.pom
```

I am executing this command, but it takes forever and got stuck here. My network is all good and I tried the command at different time but ended with the same. What might be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen all kinds of problems with this. No idea what your specific issue is but here's a few possibilities

- Your traffic is going through some kind of stateful package inspection/firewall/antivirus/IDS/bluecoat/etc and it's interfering and/or silently dropping the connection
- There's some issues validating the certificate
- The server is offline, which happens from time to time but is unlikely
- Your settings.xml file is redirectly elsewhere and that "elsewhere" location is misbehaving.

A few suggestions to work around the issue

- try disabling https (i know) by using settings.xml to remap the apache repo from https to http.
- try disabling any antivirus/firewall (temporarily) to try and isolate the problem.
- check to make sure your hard drive is not full

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot run mvn with --debug flat to see any issues to find if mvn is stuck on any command. Based on this, if you still need help, please update this question

```
mvn --debug ...
```